# Increase just width of SVG, keep height the same. Stretch SVG

Tags: css, svg

Is it possible to "scale" an SVG using the `viewBox` property (so all paths remain in tact and relative) but only have it increase the width, or height, without affecting one or the other?

For example, I have a SVG like so (I removed the code about the gradient):

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 282.47437" class="panel-2">
    <g transform="translate(-200,-356.72993)" id="layer2">
       <path d="m 200,639.2043 300,0 0,-280.56692 c 0,0 -54.42824,-13.38012 -149.6732,30.73468 C 273.74938,424.84057 200,398.89784 200,398.89784 z" 
        id="path3067"   
        style="fill:url(#radialGradient3909);fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" />
     </g>
</svg>
```

but if you resize the window, it scales in both height and width.  Can I isolate it to only adjust one of those properties or put a cap like `max-height:300px` through CSS?

I would want to "stretch" it, so the width would increase, but not the height, as the canvas enlarges, keeping the paths in tact.  Is this possible?

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/kz7dh59n/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Give the `svg` element a fixed `height="282.47437"` and `width="100%"` and set the `preserveAspectRatio="none"`.

<kbd>**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kz7dh59n/1/)**</kbd>

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 282.47437" class="panel-2" height="282.47437" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs id="defs3053">
    <linearGradient id="linearGradient3897">
      <stop id="stop3899" style="stop-color:#282828;stop-opacity:1" offset="0" />
      <stop id="stop3901" style="stop-color:#161616;stop-opacity:1" offset="1" />
    </linearGradient>
    <radialGradient cx="214.41734" cy="475.73941" r="150.5" fx="214.41734" fy="475.73941" id="radialGradient3909" xlink:href="#linearGradient3897" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(0.2897714,1.1015688,-1.5801648,0.73906298,951.79987,-143.74246)"
    />
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(-200,-356.72993)" id="layer2">
    <path d="m 200,639.2043 300,0 0,-280.56692 c 0,0 -54.42824,-13.38012 -149.6732,30.73468 C 273.74938,424.84057 200,398.89784 200,398.89784 z" id="path3067" style="fill:url(#radialGradient3909);fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" />
  </g>
</svg>
```